# How do I perform a lookup on a field in an array nested in another array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection (tables) that has documents of the form:

```
{
  "tableName": "Items",
  "rows": [
    {
      "label": "row 1 label here",
      "items": ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
    },
    {
      "label": "row 2 label here",
      "items": ["item4", "item5", "item6"]
    }
  ]
}
```

And I have another collection (items) that has documents of the form:

```
{
  "id": "item1",
  "name": "Item name",
  "code": "XXX-XXXX-XXXX",
  "price": 100
}
```

Now I want to query all items in a given table, so I am using the following aggregation:

```
{
  "$lookup": {
    from: "items",
    localField: "rows.items",
    foreignField: "id",
    as: "rows.items"
  }
}
```

So I am expecting all of "item1", "item2", ... to be replaced with their corresponding documents as such:

```
{
  "tableName": "Items",
  "rows": [
    {
      "label": "row 1 label here",
      "items": [
        {
          "id": "item1",
          "name": "Item name",
          "code": "XXX-XXXX-XXXX",
          "price": 100
        },
        ... // the rest of the items
      ]
    },
    ... // the rest of the rows
  ]
}
```

But instead, "rows" is returned as an object, containing only the first object in the expected array, and the label field is even gone:

```
{
  "tableName": "Items",
  "rows": { // <-- rows is returned as on object, should be array
    "items": [  // <-- the "label" field is missing
      {
        "id": "item1",
        "name": "Item name",
        "code": "XXX-XXXX-XXXX",
        "price": 100
      },
      ... // the rest of the items
    ]
  }
}
```

**Edit:** here are the Schemas for "row", "item" and "table" respectively:

```
const RowSchema = new Schema({
  label: String,
  items: [String]
}, {
  _id: false
})

const ItemSchema = new Schema({
  id: String,
  name: String,
  code: String,
  price: Number
}, {
  _id: false
})

const TableSchema = new Schema({
  tableName: String,
  rows: [RowSchema]
})
```

So how do I preserve the outer array and the missing fields?

Comment: Are you using mongoose?

Comment: @jQueeny yes (the question is tagged with mongoose).

Comment: Thank you, yes I can see that. The answer provided by @ray should be upvoted and will meet your needs. If you were to provide your schema I can show you how to use the mongoose `populate` method. Would I be correct in assuming the `rows.items` is an array of `ObjectId`s corresponding to the `_id` matching `ObjectId` from the `items` collection or are they strings? From what I gather you need to anonymise the schema which is fine.

Comment: No, currentyl `rows.items` is a string array, not an `ObjectId` array, but if it is only possible with `ObjectId` arrays, or if it simplifies the pipeline, then I would definitely change it this way,

Comment: Also, which schema do you mean?

Comment: So the `tables` collection will have a schema. Within that schema `rows` will either be a schema or inline definition. Can you post both? `rows.items` would need to be array of `ObjectId`s where each one matches the `_id` of the corresponding `item` from the `items` collection. Mongoose can store a reference and using the referenced model you can efficiently replace the `ObjectId`s with full documents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another option is to avoid `$unwind` and `$group` back, and replace them with `$reduce` and `$map`:

```
db.tables.aggregate([
  {$set: {items: {$reduce: {
          input: "$rows",
          initialValue: [],
          in: {$concatArrays: ["$$value", "$$this.items"]}
  }}}},
  {$lookup: {
      from: "items",
      localField: "rows.items",
      foreignField: "id",
      as: "itemsLookup"
  }},
  {$set: {
      rows: {$map: {
          input: "$rows",
          as: "row",
          in: {$mergeObjects: [
              "$$row",
              {items: {$map: {
                    input: "$$row.items",
                    as: "item",
                    in: {
                      $arrayElemAt: [
                        "$itemsLookup",
                        {$indexOfArray: ["$itemsLookup.id", "$$item"]}
                      ]
                  }
              }}}
          ]}
      }},
      itemsLookup: "$$REMOVE",
      items: "$$REMOVE"
  }}
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/zk65f4YaNdV)

- I agree with @ray on the recommendation to reconsider your schema according to your needs

Answer (score 4):

This is the reason why I am personally against the usage of nested arrays. It introduces unnecessary complexity to the queries.

You may need to `$unwind` twice at `rows` and `rows.items` level to flatten the arrays. Perform the `$lookup` and `$mergeObjects` with the lookup result. You will then need to do 2 `$group` to revert back to your original structure.

```js
db.tables.aggregate([
  {
    "$unwind": "$rows"
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$rows.items"
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "items",
      "localField": "rows.items",
      "foreignField": "id",
      "as": "itemsLookup"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$itemsLookup"
  },
  {
    "$set": {
      "rows": {
        "$mergeObjects": [
          "$rows",
          "$itemsLookup"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "label": "$rows.label"
      },
      "tableName": {
        "$first": "$tableName"
      },
      "rows": {
        "$push": "$rows"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id._id",
      "tableName": {
        "$first": "$tableName"
      },
      "rows": {
        "$push": {
          "label": "$_id.label",
          "items": "$rows"
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WP_vNq_u1C7)

---

If you find yourself working at `rows.items` level frequently, consider refactoring the schema to store the entries as individual documents like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/NWstyXL9Aoe). You can gain potential performance boost through indexing too.

Comment: Thank you, this is not exactly what I am after but it guided me in the right direction.